Cannot run nodejs in windows
I have binary folder for nodejs and now I would like to run it in windows OS, but get the error like:
The procedure entry point GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime couild not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll

Any idea?

The function GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime was introduced in Windows 8 respectively Windows Server 2012. Therefore you need a Windows version that is equal or newer than these versions.
Based in the error message it seems that you are using an outdated Windows version. Upgrade your Windows to use Node.js.
